# How to avoid duplication documentation with angular

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

I'm writing a documentation with angular.

For now, i duplicate twice the code. Once in the button.component.html to make the componenbt appear, and the other is injected from the button.component.ts as a string so it's not interpreted.

The goal is to show the result you will get if you tips the code contain in pre balise.

I need to avoid these duplication cause when a component change, i need to modify twice the code.

I first have use  to simulate include comportement but it's not working as the final content is the generated content and not the original content.

Then i checked how angular material perform for their documentation, and it's same to be a bit tricky and complicated for me has they inject their component as dependancies.

I'm asking if there is a sample way to avoid this duplication content and if someone have faced the same issue.

I have only one idea, it's to run a shell commande in the end of ng build with webpack and node, and get the content of the target block and inject directely in the target balise.

Sample :

```
<div class="my-5" data-source="myButton">
  <button mat-button>
    <mat-icon class="icon-left">help</mat-icon>
    Support center
  </button>
</div>
<code data-target="myButton"></code>
```

But i'm not very sur about that solution.

Thanks in advance.

Kevin

Comment: Please post your code as text, not images. As someone who can't access imgur, right now, your question doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing. How can i modify my post ? Is not very clear..

Comment: Explain what you want to achieve. Give your actual code and your epxected code, speak in details about the end result. And I don't want to be mean, but if you could make some effort about your sentences construction, that would help too, as it can be hard to understand poorly constructed sentences.

Comment: I think the image show perfectly the result i wanted to have. I don't know how to modify my post. There isn't an edit button so if you can show me where can i modify it it would help me and i will appreciate this. Thanks.

Comment: `As someone who can't access imgur` ... And there's a button, at the bottom-left part of the post : `share   edit   close   flag`. You can click on `edit` to change it.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand why people don't get access to imgur ? Stackoverflow is not good enough to have his own upload file system ? My request is very hard to explain without that image, it's for that that you don't have understand my request.  It's a shame to have the hability to show image but that an moderator come and delete it. Thanks you for the specification of the button, it's little hard to find and see it.. another UX problem i think.

Comment: Because I am behind a corporate proxy that filters websites given their meta tags, and imgur is an imageboard, which is prohibited in my company. Look, I was trying to help you here. If you can't identify your issue and explain it, then you probably won't get help at all. As far as I'm concerned, I can't do anything more here, so good luck with your issue, I hope you find a solution !

Comment: Thanks you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who have face the same problem, there is the module you have to use :

exemplify-angular

It's do the job perfectly.

Kevin